# $e^{-(t+1)}$ is not a function in $L_2[0,\infty)$ ?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am reading the textbook `A Course in Robust Control Theory: A Convex Approach (Ch 3.3.2)`. My question is the following example:

[image]

I have no idea why $u(t)$ is not in $L_2[0,\infty)$ ?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |u(t)|_2^2dt = \int_{-1}^{\infty} e^{-2(t+1)} dt =e^{-2}\frac{e^{-2t}}{-2}=e^{-2}(0+\frac{e^2}{2})<\infty$$

It meets the requirement of being in $L_2$.  I do not know why it is not.

Comment: I guess it is because the function is noncausal.

Comment: I guess the reason is that: $u(t)$ is a function in $L_2[-1, \infty)$.